# How can I add image source file info into a new array inside of another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing an assignment and need to dynamically create a table and add 20 image slices (1 in each cell) to make a whole picture. I have found some code that I can adapt to suit what I need but I am stuck getting the image src info for each image into the new arrays created inside another array.

```js
function addTable() {
  var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("item_image")
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

  table.border = '0'
  table.appendChild(tableBody);

  var columns = new Array();
  columns[0] = ""
  columns[1] = ""
  columns[2] = ""
  columns[3] = ""
  columns[4] = ""

  var rows = new Array();
  rows[0] = new Array("img 1", "img 2", "img 3", "img 4", "img 5");
  rows[1] = new Array("img 6", "img 7", "img 8", "img 9", "img 10");
  rows[2] = new Array("img 11", "img 12", "img 13", "img 14", "img 15");
  rows[3] = new Array("img 16", "img 17", "img 18", "img 19", "img 20");

  //TABLE COLUMNS
  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement('TH')
    th.width = '75';
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(columns[i]));
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  //TABLE ROWS
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    for (j = 0; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD')
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rows[i][j]));
      tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="item_image">
    <input type="button" id="create" value="Click here" onclick="Javascript:addTable()">
  </div>
  I've put "img" in the cells purely to show what I mean. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming those string will be image paths. You are creating a text node not an image element:

```
var td = document.createElement('td');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = rows[i][j];
td.appendChild(img);
tr.appendChild(td);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new `img` element inside of your `for` loops and set the source (*and possible other properties*) to it. This element will then be added to the table cell, as you did with the text before.

```js
function addTable() {
  var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("item_image")
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

  table.border = '0'
  table.appendChild(tableBody);

  var columns = new Array();
  columns[0] = ""
  columns[1] = ""
  columns[2] = ""
  columns[3] = ""
  columns[4] = ""

  var rows = new Array();
  rows[0] = new Array("img 1", "img 2", "img 3", "img 4", "img 5");
  rows[1] = new Array("img 6", "img 7", "img 8", "img 9", "img 10");
  rows[2] = new Array("img 11", "img 12", "img 13", "img 14", "img 15");
  rows[3] = new Array("img 16", "img 17", "img 18", "img 19", "img 20");

  //TABLE COLUMNS
  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement('TH')
    th.width = '75';
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(columns[i]));
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  //TABLE ROWS
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    for (j = 0; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
    
      // create the 'img' element
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      
      // set properties, like 'src', 'alt' and 'title'
      // for demo purpose i've used some dummy images herem you ma just use 'img.src = rows[i][j];'
      img.src = "https://dummyimage.com/100x75/000/fff&text=" + rows[i][j];
      img.alt = rows[i][j];
      img.title = rows[i][j];
    
      var td = document.createElement('TD')
      
      // add the new image element to your cell
      td.appendChild(img);

      tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
}
```

```css
table { 
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table td { 
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="item_image">
    <input type="button" id="create" value="Click here" onclick="Javascript:addTable()">
  </div>
  I've put "img" in the cells purely to show what I mean. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got this to work with some modifications but now need to remove all the gaps between rows and cells to make a complete picture. I've tried setting table border/margin/padding to 0 and also tried border collapse but nothing seems to be working. I know it's probably something really simple that I'm missing but I can't see it. Can you help? TIA.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use some css. See my updated answer @bperc